# Passing data to external function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var compliments = {
    complimentLocation: '.compliment',
    currentCompliment: '',
    complimentList: {
        'morning': mycompliments.morning,
        'afternoon': mycompliments.afternoon,
        'evening': mycompliments.evening
    },
    updateInterval: mycompliments.interval || 30000,
    fadeInterval: mycompliments.fadeInterval || 4000,
    intervalId: null
};

compliments.updateCompliment = function () {

    var _list = [];

    var hour = moment().hour();

    if (hour >= 3 && hour < 12) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['morning'].slice();
    } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 17) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['afternoon'].slice();
    } else if (hour >= 17 || hour < 3) {
        _list = compliments.complimentList['evening'].slice();
    } else {
        Object.keys(compliments.complimentList).forEach(function (_curr) {
            _list = _list.concat(compliments.complimentList[_curr]).slice();
        });
    }

    var _spliceIndex = _list.indexOf(compliments.currentCompliment);

    if (_spliceIndex !== -1) {
        _list.splice(_spliceIndex, 1);
    }

    var _randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * _list.length);
    compliments.currentCompliment = _list[_randomIndex];

    $('.compliment').updateWithText(compliments.currentCompliment, compliments.fadeInterval);

}

compliments.init = function () {

    this.updateCompliment();

    this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        this.updateCompliment();
    }.bind(this), this.updateInterval)

}


function functionToLoadFile(){
    jQuery.get('js/mycompliments.js', function(data) {

        var compliments = {
            complimentLocation: '.compliment',
            currentCompliment: '',
            complimentList: {
                'morning': mycompliments.morning,
                'afternoon': mycompliments.afternoon,
                'evening': mycompliments.evening
            },
            updateInterval: mycompliments.interval || 30000,
            fadeInterval: mycompliments.fadeInterval || 4000,
            intervalId: null


        };

        console.log(compliments);

        setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);
    });
    compliments.reload = function (compliments) {

        compliments.updateCompliment(compliments);
    }
}
setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);
```

WIth the last function `functionToLoadFile` I'm loading an external file and reseting the value of `compliments` every 5 seconds.

So far everything works (compliments gets the new value), but I'm failing to pass the new value onto `updateCompliment`, triggering its function and updating the value on the frontend.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

This is the external file that is loaded on pageload, and after every 5 seconds:

```
var mycompliments = {
    morning: [
        'Good morning, handsome!',
        'Enjoy your day!',
        'How was your sleep?'
    ],
    afternoon: [
        'etc'
    ],
    evening: [
        'weiik'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `data` parameter from within your `jQuery.get()` callback?  Whats the point of even making the call if you aren't going to use data that you get back from it?

Comment: @zero298  Somehow compliments gets updated anyway!

Comment: if i get it right you call it like with compliment as an argument "compliments.updateCompliment(compliments);" but not recieving it compliments.updateCompliment = function (missing)..

Comment: @delueg In the console I see compliment getting updated when the external file changes (therefore is loaded), but I fail to pass this data to updateCompliments() and trigger it to refresh the frontend.

Comment: Where is `mycompliments` declared?  I don't see a declaration in the code you have provided.

Comment: So you're relying on loading a script that is added to the DOM thanks to `jQuery.get()` and then using the variable declarations from there.  This seems really hacky.  Why not turn mycompliments into a JSON file, load it at startup using `.get()` and then use the actual data parameter from your callback with `JSON.parse()` which you use to actually update `compliments`?

Comment: updateCompliment  complement function does not take any parameter. So if you pass the new value as parameter to function, then it should work

Comment: @Dreamweaver He's reloading a JavaScript file and populating global scope and then pulling the data from out of global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
compliments.updateCompliment = function () {
```

to:

```
compliments.updateCompliment = function (compliments) {
```

and in functionToLoadFile() change the ajax call to:

```
jQuery.get('js/mycompliments.js', function(data) {

    var compliments1 = {
        complimentLocation: '.compliment',
        currentCompliment: '',
        complimentList: {
            'morning': mycompliments.morning,
            'afternoon': mycompliments.afternoon,
            'evening': mycompliments.evening
        },
        updateInterval: mycompliments.interval || 30000,
        fadeInterval: mycompliments.fadeInterval || 4000,
        intervalId: null
    };

    console.log(compliments1);
    compliments.updateCompliment(compliments1);
    setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);
});
```

But most importantly read some tutorial about the concept of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load a JavaScript file and read data out of it directly.  It's kind of bad practice.  Convert your **mycompliments.js** file to **JSON** and load it using the `get()` as you were.  Then use the data parameter from your callback to actually populate the data.

I'd also suggest you use a linter.

**js/mycompliments.json**

```
{
    "morning": [
        "Good morning, handsome!",
        "Enjoy your day!",
        "How was your sleep?"
    ],
    "afternoon": [
        "etc"
    ],
    "evening": [
        "weiik"
    ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
/*jslint browser: true, nomen: true*/
/*global jQuery, moment*/

(function () {

    "use strict";

    // Function to do UI updates
    function updateUI(compliments) {

        var _list = [],
            hour = moment().hour(),
            _spliceIndex,
            _randomIndex;

        if (hour >= 3 && hour < 12) {
            _list = compliments.complimentList.morning.slice();
        } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 17) {
            _list = compliments.complimentList.afternoon.slice();
        } else if (hour >= 17 || hour < 3) {
            _list = compliments.complimentList.evening.slice();
        } else {
            Object.keys(compliments.complimentList).forEach(function (_curr) {
                _list = _list.concat(compliments.complimentList[_curr]).slice();
            });
        }

        _spliceIndex = _list.indexOf(compliments.currentCompliment);

        if (_spliceIndex !== -1) {
            _list.splice(_spliceIndex, 1);
        }

        _randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * _list.length);
        compliments.currentCompliment = _list[_randomIndex];

        jQuery(".compliment")
            .updateWithText(compliments.currentCompliment, compliments.fadeInterval);

    }

    // Function to deal with updating compliments
    function updateCompliments() {
        jQuery.get("js/mycompliments.json", function (data) {

            var jsonData,
                compliments;

            // Parse data
            jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

            // Update with gotten data
            compliments = {
                complimentLocation: ".compliment",
                currentCompliment: "",
                complimentList: {
                    "morning": jsonData.morning,
                    "afternoon": jsonData.afternoon,
                    "evening": jsonData.evening
                },
                updateInterval: jsonData.interval || 30000,
                fadeInterval: jsonData.fadeInterval || 4000,
                intervalId: null
            };

            updateUI(compliments);

            // Do this again in a little while
            setTimeout(updateCompliments, compliments.updateInterval);
        });
    }

    // Run update at DOM load
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateCompliments);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `compliments.updateCompliment(compliments);`is not getting called because it is wrapped within an `compliments.reload`function.

You can make it work by calling the global `compliments.updateCompliment`function and passing `compliments` as the parameter.

However, a few things to point out are

1. `var compliments` is defined repeatedly and hence shadowed by the one inside `functionToLoadFile`
2. `setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);`is being called inside another `setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);`, it seems like `functionToLoadFile` is called not only every 5 seconds but after the file is loaded, it triggers another `setTimeout` please check that out.

what you can do is

1. removed the first `var compliments`
2. replace `compliments.updateCompliment = function () {`
   with `var updateCompliment = function(compliments) {`
3. replace `setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);` after `console.log` to `window.updateCompliment(compliments)`
4. you can remove the `compliments.reload`function too I guess.

you can learn more about javascript [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)